# What's the procedure for registering an IFilter with Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, ifilter

I tried to register my custom `IFilter` with Sharepoint 2013 to no avail. I "creatively varied" the registration steps that worked for Sharepoint 2007 and Sharepoint 2010 but without success.

Is there a detailed step-by-step description of the procedure for registering custom `IFilter`s with Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the PowerShell in this article.  PowerShell command is:  New-SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormat

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/05/13/how-to-implement-a-custom-ifilter-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since the enterprise search was rebuilt to use FAST the overall process should be different.  I cannot seem to find anything specific for SP 2013, but you may want to try this resource which identifies the steps that were used with FAST for SP 2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795798(v=office.14).aspx