# Do we need Adobe IFILTER inside SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search, ifilter

I found this link which talks about Adobe Ifilter [Adobe Ifilter](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/Acrobat_Reader_IFilter_configuration.pdf)

now we will be working on pdf files inside our document library , but seems Sharepoint 2013 already index and search pdf documents by default. so do we need to install Adobe Ifilter inside SP 2013 ? i mean will it provides additional capabilities not included within SP 2013 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, You dont need the PDF iflter for SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2013 Search now supports PDF iFilter natively.

https://sharepointthing.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/sharepoint-2013-search-natively-supports-pdf-ifilter/

also check this discussion on SE [Does Sharepoint 2013 support IFilters?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65003/does-sharepoint-2013-support-ifilters)

Comment: There are also some features that may change depending on what client application is installed. When we had Adobe PDF (Reader) installed on our machines when clicking a PDF from within the search results Acrobat highlighted the search term within the document - which is really helpful. Now that we have FoxIt as the default PDF reader that feature is gone. (AFAIK they (FoxIt) offer support for this, but not OOTB).