# Search Based .OCR Content

Tags: 2013, search

I am looking forward to a solution or thoughts for my requirement.I have document library where i will upload document into it,specifically .OCR(Scanned Document).Now i want to search content inside the scanned Documents(.OCR).

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Are your original image files in the .tiff format?

Answer (score 0):

To a certain extent SharePoint 2013 can index .tif files using its built-in TIFF iFilter.  Problem is that it is not turned on by default and may not be installed on the windows server.

This article explains how to configure SharePoint 2013 to use the iFilter.  I provided the text of the article for posterity. Visit the actual article for further clarification.

[Enabling OCR of TIFF images for SharePoint 2013 Search](http://trentacular.com/2013/08/enabling-ocr-of-tiff-images-for-sharepoint-2013-search/)

**Enabling OCR of TIFF images for SharePoint 2013 Search**

SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Search has the built-in ability to OCR and index the content of your scanned tiff images during a crawl (whether they are are stored in SharePoint or not). This is a very powerful feature, yet a bit mysterious to configure as the configuration steps have changed since the 2010 version. I’ll outline the steps below:

Using Server Manager, ensure the Windows TIFF iFilter feature is enabled on each crawl server

**Windows TIFF iFilter Feature**
Open the Local Group Policy Editor and locate the OCR folder beneath Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates.

**Group Policy Editor**
Edit the policy setting for “Select OCR languages from a code page”.  Choose Enabled and select the appropriate languages.

**Select OCR Languages**
Open the SharePoint Management Shell (using Run as Administrator) and run the following commands to configure content parsing for TIFF images.

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
New-SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormat -SearchApplication $ssa tif "TIFF Image File" "image/tiff"
New-SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormat -SearchApplication $ssa tiff "TIFF Image File" "image/tiff"
```

Restart the SharePoint Search Host Controller service.
Restart Search Host Controller Service

**Open the Search Service Application administration.**
Under the Crawling navigation item, navigate to File Types.  Add two new File Types for tif and tiff.Add File Type

**Perform a Full Crawl of your content.**
Depending on how many TIFF images are crawled, this may be a considerably longer amount of time than your previous crawl time.  Additional planning may be necessary, such as potentially scoping a Content Source to only content that should be OCR’d, or adjusting crawl schedules.

---

If your server doesn't have the iFilter installed here are a couple of articles to help:

[Windows TIFF IFilter Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd834685.aspx)

[Does Sharepoint 2013 support IFilters?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65003/does-sharepoint-2013-support-ifilters)

Answer (score 0):

Any solution with OCR requires the same thing, the OCR software must produce a file that a SharePoint Format Handler (2013) or iFilter (2010 and 2013) can read during indexing. SharePoint does not perform the recognition, it just reads the embedded text.

Depending on your budget PDF may be a better format as the performance of the 2013 format handler is significantly better that iFilter performance in general. The challenge with the TIFF iFilter referred to in other answers and sources is that it performs very poorly under load.